# How to run a server side function on a loop with NextJS?

Tags: node.js, next.js, backend

In my NextJS project, there is a setInterval function in `airdropLoop.ts` that I would like to automatically run after `next dev` or `next start` is called. Is this possible?

Edit: My NextJS project is for public APIs only, so there are no client pages / ability to run useEffect()/getServerSideProps(). The tl;dr is that one of my public endpoints simply adds items to a DB. The airdropLoop.ts should be running in the background every minute and checking if new items have been added. I want it to happen on a loop because it will be more efficient to wait for the DB to fill up a bit than running a function anytime something is added to the DB. I would rather not use a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetServerSideProps` to run the function on the server before the page is rendered. So you can run it when the user loads your homepage. You can also use `GetInitialProps` on the `_app.js` page to run some server side code this will ensure that it is always run but is not recommended.

You can also achieve this by making a server route in the `/api` directory and utilizing reacts `useEffect` to make a request to this route.

Comment: Realize I made not have been descriptive enough. Made an edit, but basically I don't have any client facing pages.

Comment: Maybe use [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware)? This will run on every request but initially you could run your function then update something to prevent it from running on each subsequent request? NextJS doesn't seem like the best candidate in this scenario, i'd recommend Express if you don't want to find a hacky work around.